# how to use derived store in svelte

Tags: svelte

I have the following store in svelte

```
const data = writable([
  {id: 1, country: "USA", population: 350},
  {id: 2, country: "Germany", population: 85},
  {id: 3, country: "Russia", population: 145},
])
```

I would like to derive from this data, and whenever it's updated, a new store. Specifically, I would like to extract the country names from the first store, to be as keys for the second store. Currently, I hard code the store like this

```
 const coordinates = writable({
   USA: { x: 0, y: 0},
   Germany: { x: 0, y: 0 },
   Russia: { x: 0, y: 0},
 });
```

However, the `data` store will be updated inside my `svelte` application, by adding or deleting properties, and I would like the `coordinates` store to be in synch with these updates. I know there is `derived`, but I am not sure how to utilize it. Currently, and as workaround, what I do is whenever and wherever I update the `data` store, I update the `coordinates` store. This is not optimal and efficient since `derived` store should take care of the updates automatically. How can I do this using the `derived` store?

Comment: Would it be okay that the coordinates are all reset to `{ x: 0, y: 0}` whenever the data store changes and the derived coordinates automatically update, or should maybe different values be preserved?

Comment: @Corrl No, after initialization to `{x:0, y:0}` I would like these values to keep their most recent values. In other words, when adding a new entry, I just initialize the new entry, and keep the rest of the store the same.

Answer (score 2):

A `derived` store can not be used in this case, since you want to modify the `coordinates` x and y axis. In this case, the `coordinates` wouldn't be `derived` from `data` anymore.

Probably the easiest way to solve this is by subscribing to `data` and adding new objects to `coordinates` and removing old ones.

This example would fulfill your usecase:

```
  let coordinates = {};
  data.subscribe(d => {
    const countries = d.map(x => x.country);
    countries.forEach(c => {
      if((c in coordinates === false)) {
        coordinates[c] = {x: 0, y: 0};
      }
    });
    Object.keys(coordinates).forEach(c => {
      if(countries.indexOf(c) < 0) {
        delete coordinates[c];
      }
    });
  });
```